# Handler postDelayed after onPause

Tags: android

I'm using handler postDelayed to move the activity to background after moments.

What happens if the activity goes to pause mode before handler fires callback? What happens to it? Is it removed or it counts down after resume?

For example when there is 5 second to callback fire if activity goes to pause after resume, does it get fired after 5 second?

Comment: Isn't it easier to write a test case and find out for yourself, than it is to post an admittance to the world that you're too lazy to do a little research?

Comment: @mah It's not just a small test, there are a lot of scenarios that can happen. I want to know the mechanism from an expert.

Comment: Unless the question is much more complicated than you've posted, it should not take more than a dozen lines of code to write a test with a handler that presents a toast. If you think about it a little more I'm sure you can come up with a simple test.

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel any pending Handler callbacks in `onPause()`.

> I'm using handler postDelayed to move the activity to background after moments.

It makes no sense to pause any Activity that is already paused. It my even be destroyed by the OS so you cannot rely on whether or not the Handler executes it's callback anyway.

You can use any of Handler's `remove___()` methods like [`removeCallbacks(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29).